# How to activate commands around a tagged entity with command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I am trying to set the score of a person within two blocks of a tagged armor stand, but the commands I thought would work don't.

I have tried

```
execute at @e[tag=GFlag] run scoreboard players add  @a[scores{dropFlag1.0=0},team=Red,distance=..2] 1
```

and

```
execute at @a[team=Red,scores={dropFlag1.0=0}] if entity @e[tag=GFlag,distance=..2] run scoreboard players add @a[team=Red,scores={dropFlag1.0=0}] 1
```

but neither has had the results I wanted.

Comment: Are you getting errors?  If you are, editing them into your question will go a long way to help us help you.  Also, are you allowed to use special characters like `.` in score names?  I didn't think you could, which would explain why your commands aren't working.

Comment: I am not any errors, but when I check to see if I have the score flagged, I don't. Also, .. is the way of expressing radial distance.

Comment: Turns out there was nothing wrong. Just some misunderstood things.

Comment: Then I suggest you post an answer explaining what the issue with your understanding was so that others might benefit from your experience.

Comment: I figure it was the same problem I have been having where clearing the inventory of a clear inventory fails and makes the rest of the blocks fail, but the problem also could have been that the redstone just needed a updated by breaking and replacing the redstone block whichh I figured out after some testing.

Comment: Wait, why are you using redstone?  You don't need to be using redstone, and really shouldn't, in order to enable your command blocks.

Comment: You should get an error message, because you have two spaces after your first `scoreboard players add`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a scoreboard set up, you can add one using this command:

```
/scoreboard objectives add <objective> dummy
```

The first command has 2 spaces before the `@a[...`, it misses a `=` after `scores`, and you didn't specify what objective to add 1 to.

```
execute at @e[tag=GFlag] run scoreboard players add @a[scores={dropFlag1.0=0},team=Red,distance=..2] <objective> 1
```

The second command also doesn't specify what objective to add a point to and it executes as the command block and not as any player, it only uses the players location. This is what it should look like:

```
execute as @a[team=Red,scores={dropFlag1.0=0}] at @s if entity @e[tag=GFlag,distance=..2] run scoreboard players add @a[team=Red,scores={dropFlag1.0=0}] <objective> 1
```

I'm not sure if objectives allow a `.` in their name, you can try to only use letters instead of `dropFlag1.0`. This is what it should look like:

You should also make sure that the `dropflag1.0` scoreboard objective is equal to 0 when you run the command and make sure that it exists in the first place.

Comment: You can find more help on commands in [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13508/232393) post.

Comment: It's been moved to [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354614/java-minecraft-what-are-the-basics-of-commands), although the post you linked has the new post linked in it.